# Comparison method violates its general contract exception using date

Tags: java, sorting, collections, comparator

I'm using a simple comparator below to sort by start time of a contest, but am getting the error "Comparison method violates its general contract" even though I Covered all the possibilities. Any help on what I'm missing?

```
    Collections.sort(contests, new Comparator<Contest>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Contest o1, Contest o2) {
            if (o1.getStartTime() != null && o2.getStartTime() != null) {
                if (o1.getStartTime().getTime() < o2.getStartTime().getTime()) {
                    return -1;
                }
                return 1;
            } 
            return 1;
        }
    });
```

Comment: what data time is startTime?

Comment: what is the return type of `getTime()` ?

Comment: Adding the pertinent code from Contest may help

Comment: check the documentation [compare](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#compare(T,T)) - 2nd paragraph - or Stefan's  [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59827589/85421)

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any case where it returns 0. And when looking further I see that the return value when 2 objects are compared wich have the same start times will be 1.
And because of that the following rule of the contract is violated:

```
sgn(compare(x, y)) == -sgn(compare(y, x))
```

If x and y have the same start time. sgn(1) != -sgn(1). In that case the method has to return 0.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running on Java 8, you can use:

```
List<Contest> sorted = contests.stream()
            .sorted(Comparator.comparing(contest -> contest.getStartTime().getTime(), Comparator.nullsFirst(Comparator.naturalOrder())))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Without knowing details about your startTime data type, assuming `time` mathematically comparable from your code, see below for code completeness. Adjust according to your need.

```
class Sorting {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Contest> contests = new ArrayList<>();

        contests.add(new Contest(new TimeHolder(1)));
        contests.add(new Contest(new TimeHolder(3)));
        contests.add(new Contest(new TimeHolder(2)));
        List<Contest> sorted = contests.stream()
            .sorted(Comparator.comparing(contest -> contest.getStartTime().getTime(), Comparator.nullsFirst(Comparator.naturalOrder())))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

        sorted.forEach(contest -> System.out.println(contest.getStartTime().getTime()));
    }

    static class Contest {
        TimeHolder startTime;

        public Contest(TimeHolder startTime) {
            this.startTime = startTime;
        }

        public TimeHolder getStartTime() {
            return startTime;
        }
    }
    static class TimeHolder{
        int time;

        public TimeHolder(int time) {
            this.time = time;
        }

        public int getTime() {
            return time;
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
```